# Is it possible to parent an object and have the child retain its rigid body physics?

Tags: game-engine, physics, constraints

I made a ragdoll that I would like to use in the Blender game engine. Right now it consists of six separate objects: a head, torso and four limbs. Each object has rigid body physics and the head and limbs have a rigid body hinge constraint, and child of constraint, connecting them to the torso. When I move the torso in object mode everything follows as it should, but when I run the game engine the head and limbs return to their original position. If I parent them directly they loose their physics. Is there any way to control my ragdoll with a single object so that I can translate/rotate it in object mode and yet have it behave correctly in the game engine?

p.s. I am using an armature to control the skin of the ragdoll where each armature bone is constrained to the appropriate ragdoll object.

Answer (score 2):

use the normal parenting in object mode "Ctrl+P" ,which will be neglected in the BGE  , and to add parent in the BGE use the **Parent** actuator with an **Always** sensor :

[image]